# Android kotlin - receive multidimensional array / json with loopj AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, android, json, multidimensional-array, kotlin

I try to receive multidimensional array / json and the code looks like this:

```
val client = AsyncHttpClient()
client.get("http://www.xxxxx.com/getjson.php", params, object : JsonHttpResponseHandler()
{
    override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, response: JSONObject?)
    {
        Log.d("letsSee", "look: " + response!!.toString())

    }
    override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>?, e: Throwable, response: JSONObject?)
    {
        Log.d("letsSee", "FAIL: " + response!!.toString())
    }
})
```

The JSON which I create on the server is like:

```
[{"bildid1":"422","dueluserid1":"93481837387222","duelnickname1":"Madel","duelduels1":"13","duelscore1":"8","bildid2":"1621","dueluserid2":"198477593885265","duelnickname2":"Anna","duelduels2":"25","duelscore2":"9"},{"bildid1":"250","dueluserid1":"11142","duelnickname1":"Barbaraa","duelduels1":"12","duelscore1":"6","bildid2":"261","dueluserid2":"11144","duelnickname2":"BeLLa","duelduels2":"11","duelscore2":"6"}]
```

I don't receive anything onSuccess neither onFailure. `look:` is also not getting printed.

It all works fine with normal non-multidimensional array like:

```
{"bildid1":"247","dueluserid1":"11142","duelnickname1":"Barbaraa","duelduels1":"12","duelscore1":"7","bildid2":"422","dueluserid2":"93481837387222","duelnickname2":"Madel","duelduels2":"13","duelscore2":"8"}
```

But how to do it with multidimensional?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Changing `response: JSONObject?` to `response: JSONArray?` solved the problem because apparently JSONObject is only for Arrays/Objects with Strings as keys and JSONArray for Ints as keys